# Changing/Moving an Item to another Library

Tags: library, item

How can I move an Item from a library X to a Library Y without deleting it and re-download it?

Comment: via the web? or programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Site Content and Structure to move items from one list to another list.

> On the Site Content and Structure page, select the item or multiple
>   items to move. Click Actions, and then click Move. In the Move dialog
>   box, select a destination and then click OK. The source items are
>   validated to ensure that they are compatible with the destination
>   container. If validation determines: An item is compatible, the item
>   will be moved and the Site Content and Structure page will be
>   displayed. An item is not compatible, an error message appears, and
>   the item will not be moved.

[SOURCE](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/work-with-site-content-and-structure-HA010131723.aspx#BM5)